# Load testing a TCP port

Tags: netty, load-testing

I would like to load test my Netty (TCP port 5000), Kafka, Storm project. Can someone indicate a good tool for generating load. I have looked at Jmeter TCP sampler but from what i understand it requires many EC2 instances in order to simuate 200k concurrent users?

My Netty Server is accepting short incoming TCP requests on Port 5000 Not http.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) benchmarking tool. You didn't give any details of your project, but something like:

```
wrk -H 'Host: localhost' \ 
    -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \ 
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \ 
    -d 120 -c 256 -t 16 --pipeline 256  YOUR_TESTING_URL
```

might work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jmeter for testing Tcp. or u can create a custom class which will generate netty clients.

client method

```
  @Override
    public void run()  {

        // Configure the client.
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {


            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            // p.addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG));
                            p.addLast(new ClientsHandler2());
                        }
                    });
                // Start the client.
                ChannelFuture f = b.connect(HOST, PORT).sync();
                // Wait until the connection is closed.
                f.channel().closeFuture().sync();



        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Shut down the event loop to terminate all threads.
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
```